# What is the ISERROR column in MIMIC-III's noteevents table?

Tags: mimic-iii

I see that [MIMIC-III's noteevents table](http://mimic.physionet.org/mimictables/noteevents/) contains a column `ISERROR`, which is a `CHAR(1)`, but no explanation. What does `ISERROR` represent (i.e. what error are we talking about)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Metavision workstation allows physicians to add notes relating to patients. These notes are created using template forms, which include a 'Set as Error' button as shown in the following screenshot (captured from the training notes highlighted below):

[image]

A '1' in the `ISERROR` column of the noteevents table indicates that a physician has selected the 'Set as Error' button. An example of an error is where a note has been associated with the incorrect patient.

Training notes for the Metavision system with a brief discussion of the 'Set as Error' button are available at: http://portal.mah.harvard.edu/metavision_training/pnotes.asp (see slide 89/109)